# Pymodbus Server TCP read/write

Tags: python, python-3.x, pymodbus3

Currently with the example of the pymodbus document I was able to create a server, from another PC I can read the variables that I want to monitor remotely. But when I change one of the variables in remote access, I do not know how to obtain it from the server to be processed.

Any recommendation?

Comment: is a Sync Server...

Comment: What do you mean by changing one of the variables in remote access ?